# Improving the appearance of java.awt.PopupMenu and java.awt.MenuItem?

Tags: java, awt

I'm trying to add a system tray icon, with a right click menu on the icon, for a javafx program.

The answers I've found indicate that the only way to do this is via `java.awt.SystemTray`

Which is fine, but the popup menu which shows up when I right click the icon in tray, looks very bland. Also, if I hover the mouse over any of the popup menu options, I expect the background color of that option to change, to indicate that I'm selecting it. But this doesn't happen, the menu stays completely static and unchanging until I click an option.

I'm looking for a way that I can listen to the mouseover event on a MenuItem and change its background + foreground color to indicate that it has the focus. But I can't find any methods in the API that let you do this. Is there any other way? Or is there anything else I can do to make the menu seem a bit more responsive?

Comment: Are you using the `LookAndFeel` classname of the Operating system, or the default Java L&F?

Comment: @iWumbo I'm just using the defaults. How can I use this LookAndFeel class?

Comment: Like this: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`

  However, i'm not sure if this will work. Try it. Also, the above line must be surrounded with Try-Catch. The line will take the the LookAndFeel classname of your OS.

Comment: [Try this link](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/ixmal/archive/2006/05/using_jpopupmen.html) you can get some help here